# screen that comes up by default in landscape mode with right view dislocated

Tags: ios, ipad

I'm new to iOS development and also to stackoverflow.. I will directly jump to the image and output.

This is the screen that comes up by default in landscape mode with right view dislocated
[image]

After I click and move the screen, the map gets displayed in full view like this

[image]

Please help me out as the autoresizingmask is also untouched. And by clicking and dragging itself the full view appears.

Comment: this helped me to solve it.

    CLLocationCoordinate2D worldCenter; worldCenter.latitude = 0.0 ;
    worldCenter.longitude = 0.0;
    self.mapView.centerCoordinate = worldCenter;